# VNC desktop visual bugged without screen

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remote

i can connect to my ubuntu 18.04.3 lts with VNC, with screen or without screen. The problem come with the fact that, without screen, the machine just shows a bugged desktop, not usable. I put an image to show what i see. Can anyone tell me how am i supposed to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Remmina VNC client? Your image is not shown on your question.

Comment: Sorry @Graham, i added it. I am also using VNC viewer from windows 10